# getA1Notation from each item in a range

Tags: google-apps-script

How can we return the A1Notation of each item in a range?

```
function getA1Notation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = s.getRange('A1:B3');

  for (var row in range) {
    for (var col in range[row]) 
      Logger.log(range[row][col].getA1Notation());
  }
};
```

I know we can't do it that way, but here's the results I'm expecting...

A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3

Comment: I don't know any way other than using a `getRange` (or at least an `offset`) within the loop, or using Javascript to construct the A1Notations using the top-left reference and the range size.

Comment: Yeah, an offset on the top left is what I needed, thx. `Logger.log(s.getRange('A1').offset(row, col, 1, 1).getA1Notation());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
results.formulas = getRangeFormulas(guiRange);
results.a1Notation = new Array(results.formulas.length);
var guiDataSheetName = guiRange.getSheet().getName();
for (var row in results.formulas ) {
  results.a1Notation[row] = new Array(results.formulas[row].length);      
  for (var col in results.formulas[row]) {       
    results.a1Notation[row][col] = guiDataSheetName+"!" + guiRange.offset(row,col,1,1).getA1Notation();
  }
  //Logger.log("5get data"+ (new Date().getTime() - executionTime.getTime()));
}
```

I get the sheet name outside the loop because it requires a client server call.